# Looking for the name of a particular datastructure

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a situation where I need a particular data structure, and am looking for the name of that data structure to look for prior art. I'll start by describing the actual problem, then describe the data structure I have in mind.

The requirements I have are:

- Have a dynamically sized list of elements.
- It should be possible to remove an element from the list by index.
- None of the other elements in the list should have their index changed when an item is removed.
- When I want to add an element to the list when there's a free slot, that free slot should be filled with the new element.

The datastructure I've thought up which fits those requirements is a list of elements, with an associated dynamic bitfield which keeps track of which slots are free and which are occupied. When adding to the datastructure, I find the first 1 in the bitfield and know that slot is available; when removing, I call the destructor of that element and set the associated bit in the bitfield to 0.

This datastructure is similar to a dynamic array of optional values, but looking something up in a bitfield should be way faster than looping through the array looking for a free slot.

Surely this datastructure is useful in enough that people have already implemented it, but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: first three is a `std::unordered_map<index,value>` the last bullet I dont understand

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing sounds a lot like a slot-map data structure.

- Contiguous access like a vector.
- "Indexes" don't change when an element is inserted or taken out. (they are called handles btw)
- Fast access O(1) access.
- Fast insert/erase O(1) typically

Take a look at my stl like slot-map (actually 4 of them).
https://github.com/ceorron/slot-map
All 4 have been tested. To save you some time the one that you are interested in is `slot_map<...>`.

If you need ordered elements you need `ordered_slot_map<...>` or `basic_ordered_slot_map<...>` whichever is faster.

OK?

There are stl containers `std::unordered_map<index,value>` & `std::map<index,value>` however both of these are associative containers and have a search overhead for pretty much all operations. Also you can't have duplicate keys with associative containers, which may not match your data.

I think you are describing a `slot_map`.

Comment: That seems to do almost exactly what I want, yeah. It's not using bitfields though; it would be interesting to see how that "true" but kind of complicated O(1)  insert compares to my not-quite-O(1) ~3 instructions per 32 elements it has to look through tough.

Comment: I've taken a closer look at it now, and it seems to require that you use slot_map::handle to refer to the value. It seems like even though the structure is in a vector, you can't index it with an integer - and since the items are refcounted, you need to keep the handles around in a separate structure lest items get instantly destroyed. Is that right?

In that case, this datastructure probably isn't for me. I need to be able to serialize the indexes.

Comment: Yeah, things are refcounted, you will have to keep the indexes around to stop things from getting destroyed. I did't know that you needed to serialise the indexes. There most likely is a work around that would allow you to turn handles into indexes. And then on deserialise turn them back. I had not though of that and so there is nothing in it that does that though.